# How to append a list to pandas column, series?

Tags: python, pandas, append

Asume that I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to extend `col1` with array `xtra`. However this errors out.

```
xtra = [3,4]
df['col1'].append(xtra)
```

How can I append `xtra` to `df.col1`, so that the final otuput would looks as so?

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     nan
3     4     nan
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just copy the same format you used (`dict`) to make a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

xtra = {'col1': [3,4]}

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(xtra))
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(xtra, columns=['col1']), ignore_index=True)

print(df)
  col1  col2
0     1   3.0
1     2   4.0
2     3   NaN
3     4   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add those rows without creating annother Dataframe by iterating on xtra:

```
for val in xtra:
    df = df.append({'col1' : val}, ignore_index=True)
```