# How to add unbalanced List into a dataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is My dataframe and List

```
X  Y  Z  X1
1  2  3  3
2  7  2  6
3 10  5  4
4  3  7  9
5  3  3  4

list1=[3,5,6]
list2=[4,3,7,4]
```

I want to add the lists into a data frame, I have tried some code but it gives an error and something is not working

```
#Expected Output

X  Y  Z  X1
1  2  3  3
2  7  2  6
3 10  5  4
4  3  7  9
5  3  3  4
3        4
5        3
6        7
         4    


#here is my code

list1 = [3,5, 6]
df_length = len(df1) 
df1.loc[df_length] = list1
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your code and the error you got...

Comment: list1 = [3,5, 6]
df_length = len(df1)
df1.loc[df_length] = list1

Comment: edit your post and add them in... not in the comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append a list to pandas column, series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127227/how-to-append-a-list-to-pandas-column-series)

Comment: @PV8 The question is completely different from what you are suggesting. That doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`series.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) to create the new series (`X` & `X1`), and create the output `df` using [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
s1 = df.X.append(pd.Series(list1)).reset_index(drop=True)
s2 = df.X1.append(pd.Series(list2)).reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.concat([s1, df.Y, df.Z, s2], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'X', 1: 'X1'})
```

---

```
df
    X   Y       Z   X1
0   1.0 2.0     3.0 3
1   2.0 7.0     2.0 6
2   3.0 10.0    5.0 4
3   4.0 3.0     7.0 9
4   5.0 3.0     3.0 4
5   3.0 NaN     NaN 4
6   5.0 NaN     NaN 3
7   6.0 NaN     NaN 7
8   NaN NaN     NaN 4
```

Comment: index starts with 0 with this code!, can you please solve that .

Comment: This gives the expected result!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding the index. What should it start at if not 0?

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept if it solved your problem. Cheers!

Comment: sure will do that

Comment: @CHRD Nice answer +1

Comment: @CHRD df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,2], [1,3, 4], [1,3, 4], [1,3, 4]], columns = ["X", "Y","X1"])
print(df1.head())

list1=[45,45,45]
list2=[65,65,65,65,65]

s1 = df1.X.append(pd.Series(list1)).reset_index(drop=True)
s2 = df1.X1.append(pd.Series(list2)).reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = pd.concat([s1, df1.Y, s2], axis=1)

df1.head()              is there any problem in this code? it adds only one value in dataframe of both list

Comment: Not sure I understand. This does exactly what you were asking for, except that you forgot to rename the columns.

Comment: plz run this in your system! your output was expected ! but as i run in my system! it doesn't add all elements of list

Comment: I did, and it returns a dataframe with 9 rows as expected

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark  next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

```
'''
X  Y  Z  X1
1  2  3  3
2  7  2  6
3 10  5  4
4  3  7  9
5  3  3  4
'''

list1=[3,5,6]
list2=[4,3,7,4]
ls_empty=[]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()


df1 = pd.DataFrame([list1, ls_empty, ls_empty, list2])
df1 = df1.T
df1.columns = df.columns

df2 = pd.concat([df, df1]).replace(np.nan, '', regex=True).reset_index(drop=True).astype({'X1': int})



print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   X   Y  Z  X1
0  1   2  3   3
1  2   7  2   6
2  3  10  5   4
3  4   3  7   9
4  5   3  3   4
5  3          4
6  5          3
7  6          7
8             4
```